# Share Files Between my iPad App and PC using objectiveC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My ipad app creates a CSV file that I want to copy into a windows pc at smb://windowssever/d$/myfolder.

My Windows PC needs an authetication that is it needs a username and password to connect.

I am using the following code to copy but not sure where should I give the username and password of PC in the following code.

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr copyItemAtPath: @"/tmp/myfile.csv" toPath: @"smb://windowssever/d$/myfolder/myfile.csv" error: NULL]  == YES)
        NSLog (@"Copy successful");
else
        NSLog (@"Copy failed");
```

Comment: You can ask application server to copy file on windows via PHP file (or any other script file).

Comment: @akiniwa Thanks but on Windows i cannot install any software since its a server with folder access. Also cannot install PHP on multiple iPads as there are many users who would be using the app

Comment: That's not really a valid path. You have to first mount the remote directory to some local directory. However, this is more complicated than this naive solution.

Comment: @Sulthan that is valid path i can manually copy the files to the windows server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct URI with username & password is:

```
@"smb://WORKGROUP;USERNAME:PASSWORD@windowssever/d$/myfolder/myfile.csv"
```